# nullpointer exception from string to long

Tags: android

I have in one activity:

```
...
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.configure);

        edit1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        edit2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        edit11=edit1.getText().toString();
        edit22=edit2.getText().toString();
        btn=(View) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

     public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn:
             Intent i=new Intent(this,selection.class);
             i.putExtra("code_value",edit11);
             i.putExtra("time_value",edit22);
             startActivity(i);  
             break;

     }
```

and in the selection activity:

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection);


        String code_value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("code_value");
        String time_value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("time_value");
        long thetime=Long.parseLong(time_value);
..

// Start service using AlarmManager
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        Intent intent = new Intent(selection.this, selection.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(selection.this, 0, intent,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                thetime, pintent);
```

where the long  "thetime" I want to use it in the  alarm.setRepeating.
But it gives me the nullpointerexception..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to get text  from edittext's inside button click instead of `onCreate` of Activity

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn:

             // retrieve text here from EditText 

             edit11=edit1.getText().toString();
             edit22=edit2.getText().toString();
             Intent i=new Intent(this,selection.class);
             i.putExtra("code_value",edit11);
             i.putExtra("time_value",edit22);
             startActivity(i);  
             break;

     }
```

Comment: @prasperK congrats brother 30K

Comment: @prasperK:Maybe you can help me with this?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are calling `getText()` immediately after initialisation and it always return empty String.

You need to call **getText()** exactly in the moment when you want to deal with text so you need to move it to `onClick()` method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn:
             String e1 = edit1.getText().toString();
             String e2 = edit2.getText().toString();
             Intent i=new Intent(this,selection.class);
             i.putExtra("code_value", e1);
             i.putExtra("time_value", e2);
             startActivity(i);  
             break;

     }
```

Comment: :I upvoted for you and accepted the other answer because it was first.thanks